# Issues compiling .apk file

Tags: android, android-studio, compilation, apk

I'm compiling an apk from the source code with the following settings -

```
compileSdkVersion 28
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 28
```

I want to know what gradle, build tools and dependencies I should add/use.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:**X**'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:**Y**'
```

So, basically guide me with values for X and Y, like 3.1.0 or whatever suitable. I'm not using appcompact n all in my app, only google admob ads are added so I am using this one at the moment -

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html

Comment: Your question title does not match your question body. Please make them mean same. `Issues compiling .apk file` which issues?

Comment: Thanks for the answer ADM but its still not working. I'm using - 
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'

classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following versions for your app

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'

classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

Comment: Hi Midhun. I've made the changes but its still not working. App crashes immediately after installation.

Comment: That may be due to some other issues with the app, you can analyse the logcat or share it here.

Comment: I don't have the logcat. I'm using AIDE app to compile. There are no errors during compilation but app doesn't open after installation.